# Angular Material 9 : How to fix a bug in a mat-form-field inside a mat-select

Tags: angular, material-design

I want to filter some objects inside a mat-select, but once i hit the space key in the search box, the first element get checked ! any idea how to fix this ? is it a bug with mat-select ? or maybe there's a better approach or a right way to add a search input text inside a multiple select in material desgin ?

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Books" multiple (selectionChange)="initFilter($event,'book')">
        <mat-form-field class="search-input">
            <mat-icon matPrefix>search</mat-icon>
            <input [formControl]="booksFilterCtrl" matInput>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let book of books" [value]="book">{{book.name}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

I'm using material design and angular 9

Comment: Please provide a fully working reproduction so we can see what happen. But I suggest you don't reinvent the wheel and find a package that suit your need, like this one : https://www.npmjs.com/package/mat-select-filter

Comment: Seems like mat-select-filter has the same issue as in my post ! The space key is not working and check the first value of the list by default !

Comment: Check my answer below, it fix it and might work with your own code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggested in the comment section that you use a package to do that, but it still select the item when typing a 'space'. you can add :

`(keydown)="$event.stopPropagation()"`

to disable the keyboard keydown event when typing in your search input. Works like a charm with the package I gave you : [mat-select-filter](http://npmjs.com/package/mat-select-filter).

Here is [the github thread talking about it](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10684#issuecomment-408124213).

Comment: It also worked like a charm with my solution and i didn't need an extra package :) thank you !

Comment: i have a weird problem even with the mat-select-filter package ! when i search for an element not found in my list, then i onblur on the input, the select cannot be opened and i have to reload the page !!! did you have this ??

Comment: @Kivo I supposed it is because the search input isn't cleared when the select window is closed. If I remember well there's an event for this, just empty your input at this moment and it should be fine.